# Как мне создать геттер?

Tags: c++

```
class B { ... }

class A {
private:
  vector<B *> data;
public:
  A() { ... }
  A~() {
   //прохожу по каждому элементу data и вызываю для него delete;
  }
  void set(string str) {
     data.push_back(new B(str));
  }
}
```

Теперь мне нужно создать геттер, который бы возвратил data.
Если написать так:

```
vector<B *> get() const {
  return data;
}
```

То все значения копируются. В результате мне нужно будет удалять и копию вектор. Нужно написать так, чтобы после вызова деструктора A, все значения вектора удалились, тоесть память полностью освободилась.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ссылку на вектор возвращать ?

```
vector<B *> &get() const {
  return data;
}
```

Comment: @nanotexnik, error C2440 невозможно преобразовать const в &

Comment: незаметил при копировании вашего кода, уберите const

Comment: @nanotexnik, спасибо. на автомате всем геттерам ставлю const, а вот в этом случаи и не нужно было.